# onclick from an Object's button doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I instantiate an object, with an argument which is a button. When the button of an instance
is clicked, it should run a function, but it doesn't. In the full version of the code, Chrome gives this message in the console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onclick' of undefined"

HTML:

```
<textarea id='txt' readonly rows='5' cols='40'></textarea>
<button id='btn' type='button'>click</button>
```

JS:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var txt = document.getElementById('txt');
var foo = new Foo(btn);

function Foo(btn) {
    this.button = btn;
}

Foo.prototype.buy = function() {
    txt.value = 'Foo Bar';
};

Foo.button.onclick = function() {
    foo.buy();
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yx6xu/2/)

Comment: `Foo.button` is not defined. `new Foo().button` is.

Comment: But if I wanted to not declare a new button for every Foo instance, would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you want a different button for each instance: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5rcVN/)

  ```
  var txt = document.getElementById('txt');

  function Foo(btn) {
      this.button = btn;
      btn.onclick = this.buy;
  }

  Foo.prototype.buy = function() {
      txt.value = this.value;
  };

  new Foo(document.getElementById('btn'));
  new Foo(document.getElementById('btn2'));
  ```

  If you like compact code, you could also use `(this.button = btn).onclick = this.buy;`
- If you want same button for all instances: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5rcVN/1/)

  ```
  var txt = document.getElementById('txt'),
      btn = document.getElementById('btn');

  function Foo() {

  }

  (Foo.prototype.btn = btn).onclick = Foo.prototype.buy = function() {
      txt.value = 'Foo Bar';
  };

  var a = new Foo(),
      b = new Foo();
  console.log(a === b); // false;
  console.log(a.btn === b.btn); // true;
  ```

Comment: How can I put multiple statements on the "onclick"?

Comment: @730 Use a function wrapper containing all functions e.g. `.onclick = function(){ f1(); f2(); f3(); };`, or use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Comment: Then there are some things that are wrong... See, in the actual "buy" function there are a lot of "this" that should refer to variables inside Upgrade, and apparently they are referring to the button instead of the Upgrade instance, which messes everything up. Is there some way I can make them refer to the Upgrade instance instead of the button?